# Setup Bitbucket repository for Jenkins (for Cloudbees)

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

This document is not very helpful:

https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Bitbucket

I have:

1. Added CloudBees DEV@cloud public key to the Bitbucket
2. Added the hook
3. Have installed the Jenkins Bitbucket plugin (from within Cloudbees)

But how to actually use a (Private) Bitbucket repo for a Jenkins Build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, at the end you are using a Git repository, so it is the same if your repo is in one provider or another one. So your git repo should have a Repository URL like this one below (https or ssh) and a username/password.

```
https://felix@bitbucket.org/felix/my-git-repo.git
```

So you need to enter these information on your Jenkins job->Source Code Management->Git Repositories (same thing for Forge (CloudBees), GitHub, ....)

The BitBucket plugin just let you configure Bitbucket to automatically trigger a build on commit. The method below is a workaround as the way explained on the doc doesn't work.

**On Jenkins**:

1. Get your API token from your Jenkins instance. You can get it form here:

   https://[account].ci.cloudbees.com/user/[the-user-portion-of-your-email]/configure
2. On your Jenkins job, you need to enable:

   - Trigger builds remotely (e.g, from scripts). Need to add the authentication token.
   - Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket

**On BitBucket**

1. Instead of adding a POST hook, add a Jenkins Hook.

   - Endpoint

https://[the-user-portion-of-your-email]:[apitoken]@[account].ci.cloudbees.com

NOTE: the-user-portion-of-your-email should correspond with one of the user at "People" section in Jenkins.

- Add project name = job name in Jenkins
- Add token

**UPDATE**

POST is working perfectly, CloudBees just missed the character"/" at the end of the URL used to hook the trigger. So it should be https://[account].ci.cloudbees.com/bitbucket-hook/ and NOT https://[account].ci.cloudbees.com/bitbucket-hook

Official CloudBees [BitBucket doc](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Bitbucket) are now updated.

Comment: I added the git SSH repo, and still nothing happens, I assumed that I did not have to add any username/password as I have already saved the Cloudbees Public SSH key to the Bitbucket account. So it should be able to read/write to the repo with that. What am I missing?

Comment: With the ssh protocol should be ssh://git@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git and add the CloudBees Public SSH key to the Bitbucket account. Did you try to clone the repo on your laptop?

Comment: Actually I was able to manually build with 'git@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git' without ssh:// prefix, anyway, the problem I have now is when we commit to the repo, the build does not trigger, we have to click 'Build now' manually

Comment: Then, on BitBucket. 1- https://[account].ci.cloudbees.com/bitbucket-hook and then on Jenkins 2- Build when changes are pushed to BitBucket

Comment: Well I did that, and we tested last night but even we commit the build does not trigger, so we had to stick with the Cloudbees internal git hosting which works for us

Comment: Indeed, I tested it and was not working. However, I found a workaround, which is working properly. I have updated my answer explaining how you should do the set-up. If it works, please, vote positive so other people could notice how the set-up should be done. I will update the docs after contacting with Nicolas.

Comment: Great! The build gets triggered now from Bitbucket commit

Comment: character"/" at the end of the URL saved me! Thanksss